# Conflict of tracking reference in c#

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I wrote managed class in C++/CLI:

```
public ref class Foo
{
public:
   void func1(Foo% foo){}
   void func2(Foo^% foo){}
};
```

Then, I am using methods in c# console application, like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Foo foo2 = new Foo();
foo.func1(ref foo2);  // getting error
foo.func2(ref foo2);  // OK
```

I really don't understand this difference. C# treats signature of func1 and func2 as:

```
void func1(Foo);
void func2(ref Foo);
```

Comment: `^` means `ref`.  What don't you understand?

Comment: I thought that ^ means pointer

Comment: Oh, it seems like I understood, thanks.

Comment: @SLaks, nope `^` means *managed handle*, which is implicit in C# for reference types, and equivalent to `*` in C++. `^%` means the same as C#'s `ref` if `Foo` is a reference type. `%` alone is a *tracking reference*, which has no equivalent in C# - it's like `&` in C++, think of it as an object reference which cannot be null. It's also equivalent to `ref` in C# if `Foo` is a value type. C++/CLI is *much* more explicit about this stuff. In OP's example it's the `%` that adds the `ref` semantics, the `^` is simply required by virtue of `Foo` being a reference type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   void func1(Foo% foo)
```

This is an *implicit reference*.  It is a [native C++ feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639057/what-is-implicit-dereference-in-c), equivalent to `Foo&` if Foo were an unmanaged type.  C++/CLI supports it as well, it tries to be as C++-like as it can.  To a fault sometimes, it would arguably be a lot clearer if they had permitted `Foo^&` instead.

But it is not a feature of other .NET languages, like C#, as you found out, they don't have any syntax to express the same thing.  Not in the least because these languages try to hide the differences between object references and values as much as possible.  To a fault sometimes.  It is not an MSIL feature either, requiring the C++/CLI compiler to implement it.  Much like a C++ compiler does.  The argument type is actually `Foo^` in the metadata but with [a [modopt]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.isimplicitlydereferenced(v=vs.110).aspx) to annotate the method argument.  Enough for the C# compiler to know that it is forbidden fruit, too likely to cause method overload resolution problems.

Since Foo is a reference type, you really do have to use `Foo^`.  Or `Foo^%` if you meant to pass the object reference by reference, only useful if your method creates a new Foo object.